# appsettings.json and Class libraries that use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, configurationmanager

I'm working on migrating an existing ASP.NET MVC app to ASP.NET Core. The solution has several class libraries (providing data access, services, etc). Many of those class libraries make use of the static `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]` way of getting the config from the web.config file.

With the ASP.NET Core app, though, there is no web.config file and it appears `ConfigurationManager` can't read appsettings.json.

I really like the new configuration system in ASP.NET Core, and am making use of it within the web app.

But is there a "simple" way to migrate these class libraries without having to rewrite them to use the new configuration system? Any basic replacement for the static `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]` calls that'll read appsettings.json? (note: we'll eventually rewrite them, but we'd rather do this one piece at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET Standard 2.0 you can add a reference to the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` NuGet package to get access to appSettings.

You can add an `app.Config` file (not `web.Config`) to your ASP.NET Core project to store the appSettings.  This will be copied to the output folder and renamed as `AppName.dll.config` during the project build.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying I need to do both of those, right? Just using the NuGet package doesn't seem to read the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Yes you need to do both.   The NuGet package reads the XML application configuration file (app.Config in your project, appName.dll.config after building).  It does not use appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't try this with a class library, but this worked in LinqPad:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["test"] = "test",
            ["test2:test"] = "test2"
        })
        .Build();

    foreach (var pair in config.AsEnumerable())
    {
        // Skips the (test2 = null) pair
        if (pair.Value != null)
        {
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"].Dump();
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test2:test"].Dump();
}
```

You could put something like this in your initialization code.
It sets all of the values available to the System.Configuration app setting collection.